# Flickering white lines displayed whilst playing games in high quality

Tags: crash, hardware-failure, gaming

My computer specs are

- Asus M4A88T-M
- Antec BP550 Plus 550W
- G.SKILL Ripjaws Series 8GB (2 x 4GB) 240-Pin DDR3 SD-RAM DDR3 1600 (PC3 12800) RAM
- Nvidia 550ti 1gb 192bit video card
- Anthon 2 3.2ghz x3 CPU am3

My computer seems alright but when I play games they will flicker white across the screen and some games will even crash immediately after starting it. I only have this problem with games that require high graphics settings. I noticed the white flicker in games like Minecraft but it's barely noticeable so it's not a problem. The white flickering started randomly while I was playing.

I've switched out every part of my PC except for the motherboard and processor. I've re-downloaded and re-installed Windows 3 times with different CDs, downloaded all the drivers and tried old and new ones that I could find. It is still flickering.

What can be causing this white flashing?

Comment: You got the white flashing with a different graphics card?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem with the graphic card. As your having graphical artifacts that means its not stable or perhaps a bit damaged, either way its not working as it should.
It could also mean its some bad drivers ranting around. Either way try older/newer drivers and see if that help.
If it dont i would suggest sending the graphic card in for rapair as i guess its still under warrenty?

These problems can occure differently depending on what game it is. Some games push the card in other ways and its easier to notice.
i myself had a gtx 570 that turned things nice and pink every now and then (like 10% of the total pixels were pink) and it turned out to be a defective card.
Many games also crashed with that card for more or less "no reason" so to say. Before i know it was defective that is. I got that exchaged but changed to a 6950 instead.
With my 6950 when i overclock it and forgot to change the voltage on it i get some green/blue boxes. Thats because it isnt 100% stable and i fix that myself by increasing the volt.
Now as i guess you havnt overclocked it everything should work as it should, that is no crashing and no weird white flickers. 
now i dont know what you mean with flickers but i guess its some type of artifacts or perhaps white frames?

Either way something isnt working as it should and it sounds like its the graphic cards fault which it normaly is when you get weird things on the screen like that.
But its very hard to tell without seeing what it is you mean.
Screenshot perhaps?